# parsing xml using python / elementree

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

The xml I need to search specifies but does not use a namespace:

```
    <WRMHEADER xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/DRM/2007/03/PlayReadyHeader" version="4.0.0.0">
    <DATA>
        <PROTECTINFO>
            <KEYLEN>16</KEYLEN>
            <ALGID>AESCTR</ALGID>
        </PROTECTINFO>

        <LA_URL>http://192.168.8.33/license/rightsmanager.asmx</LA_URL>
        <LUI_URL>http://192.168.8.33/license/rightsmanager.asmx</LUI_URL>

        <DS_ID></DS_ID>
        <KID></KID>
        <CHECKSUM></CHECKSUM>

    </DATA>
</WRMHEADER>
```

I'd like to read the values for various fields, e.g. data/protectinfo/keylen etc.

```
root    = ET.fromstring(sMyXml)
keylen  = root.findall('./DATA/PROTECTINFO/KEYLEN')

print root
print keylen
```

This code prints the following:

```
<Element {http://schemas.microsoft.com/DRM/2007/03/PlayReadyHeader}WRMHEADER at 0x7f2a7c35be60>
[]
```

root.find and root.findall return None or [] for this query.  I've been unable to specify a default namespace, is there a solution to querying these values?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a namespace dict:

```
x = """<WRMHEADER xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/DRM/2007/03/PlayReadyHeader" version="4.0.0.0">
    <DATA>
        <PROTECTINFO>
            <KEYLEN>16</KEYLEN>
            <ALGID>AESCTR</ALGID>
        </PROTECTINFO>

        <LA_URL>http://192.168.8.33/license/rightsmanager.asmx</LA_URL>
        <LUI_URL>http://192.168.8.33/license/rightsmanager.asmx</LUI_URL>

        <DS_ID></DS_ID>
        <KID></KID>
        <CHECKSUM></CHECKSUM>

    </DATA>
</WRMHEADER>"""
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

root = ET.fromstring(x)
ns = {"wrm":"http://schemas.microsoft.com/DRM/2007/03/PlayReadyHeader"}
keylen = root.findall('wrm:DATA', ns)

print root
print keylen
```

Now you should get something like:

```
<Element '{http://schemas.microsoft.com/DRM/2007/03/PlayReadyHeader}WRMHEADER' at 0x7fd0a30d45d0>
[<Element '{http://schemas.microsoft.com/DRM/2007/03/PlayReadyHeader}DATA' at 0x7fd0a30d4610>]
```

To get `/DATA/PROTECTINFO/KEYLEN`:

```
In [17]: root = ET.fromstring(x)

In [18]: ns = {"wrm":"http://schemas.microsoft.com/DRM/2007/03/PlayReadyHeader"} 
In [19]: root.find('wrm:DATA/wrm:PROTECTINFO/wrm:KEYLEN', ns).text
Out[19]: '16'
```

Comment: No worries, if you are doing a lot of work with xml in python you might find lxml useful http://lxml.de/

Answer (score 1):

I'm wondering if this will also work.  Please post your comments on pros and cons of this approach.

```
from xml.dom.minidom import parse
import xml.dom.minidom

# Open XML document using minidom parser
DOMTree = xml.dom.minidom.parse("xmlquestion.xml")
tn = DOMTree.documentElement
print tn.namespaceURI
#print tn.childNodes

data = tn.getElementsByTagName('DATA')[0]
protectinfo = data.getElementsByTagName('PROTECTINFO')[0]
keylen = protectinfo.getElementsByTagName('KEYLEN')[0]
print keylen.childNodes[0].data

http://schemas.microsoft.com/DRM/2007/03/PlayReadyHeader
16
```

Comment: That's great.  I had to slightly modify to import parseString as my data source came from a network request.  I was just looking for a quick way to validate the xml content.  I wanted to go with ET, since it appears to be more widely used, although I found this problem frustrating, since documentation seemed lacking and it seemed like such a fundamental issue.